# select from data frame rows with a condition in r

Tags: r

have a list like that:

```
        name   A  B  C  age
        Ben    1  0  0  20
        Adam   0  0  0  45
        Sally  0  1  0  51
        Jack   0  0  1  32
```

I want to select to only the rows (with all the columns) that has 1 in A,B or C.
the code:

```
has_ones <- list[(list$A==1)|(list$B==1)|(list$C==1),]
```

I got this:

```
    name   A  B  C  age
    Ben    1  0  0  20
    Adam   1  0  0  45
    Sally  1  0  0  51
    Jack   1  0  0  32
```

can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things were wrong:

1. Use `|` instead of `||`
2. You were missing the `,`

   ```
   has_ones <- list[(list$A==1)|(list$B==1)|(list$C==1),]
   ```

> ```
>    name A B C age
> 1   Ben 1 0 0  20
> 3 Sally 0 1 0  51
> 4  Jack 0 0 1  32
> ```

Please see Peter's comment below for a more concise syntax.

Comment: tnx, try that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Whilst it is great to answer the question using OP's syntax, it may also be of benefit to add a more concise approach `subset(list, A == 1 | B == 1 | C == 1)`

Comment: @ella please specify what exactly "it still doesn't work" means. Did you try the code on the example? Does it not work with the actual data? What is the errant output?

Comment: it just copied that list and add 1 to all in A column and 0 in B and C column.

Comment: I can verify that the solution does work for the example you provided. Please add the above solution and the result you receive by editing your question.

Comment: it works now, thank you.